# Issues with Drupal's autocomplete test with Behat

Tags: autocomplete, behat

I'm trying to test a form generated by Drupal where there are some autocompletion to help people do the right choice.

In this form, there are 3 fields that let the user select 3 articles ('Actualités'), and once you start typing things, the auto-completes generates a list of Articles that have a similar title.

Here is an example:

[image: behat1]

The problem is that I realized while doing some tests that using `$this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField()` makes Behat loose focus on the field, like if it presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> once done filling the field.

So I tried a lot of tricks to gain focus of this field, like the following:

```
$field = $this->getSession()->getPage()->findField('field_mb_actualites[0][target_id]');

if($field) {

  // Solution #1
  // the dropdown menu is inside a `ul#ui-id-1` element
  $this->getSession()->executeScript("jQuery('#ui-id-1').show();");

  // Solution #2     
  $field->focus();

  // Solution #3
  // Consists of pressing "shift + tab" for a "reverse tab" and trying to get back to the field

  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyDown($xpath, 16);
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyDown($xpath, 9);
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyUp($xpath, 9);
  $this->getSession()->getDriver()->keyUp($xpath, 16);

  // And I take a screenshot at the end to see if anything worked
  file_put_contents('screenshot-focus.png', $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getScreenshot());
}
```

But I always get the same result, which is the following:

[image: behat]

All I need to do once I have the focus is to press the "right" directional arrow to make the dropdown visible again, then the "down" directional arrow to select a suggestion, then "Enter" to confirm the choice.

However, I'm starting to run out of ideas, even though I found a couple questions on Behat's github about this problem, but I couldn't manage to make the answers work. How can I trigger the auto-complete?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you are trying to do? trigger the autocomplete or hide it?

Comment: Triggering it (i'll edit my question to precise this)

Comment: You need to create a script that triggers the right event that shows the autocomplete and execute it after you fill the field, tomorrow I can write you an example.The event that you need to trigger can be found via inspect on that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JavaScript function to trigger the event like this:

```html
    public function triggerEventOn($css_selector){
        $function = <<<JS
        (function(){
        var element = document.querySelector("$css_selector");
        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('change', true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
        })()
JS;

        try{
            $this->getSession()->getDriver()->executeScript($function);
        }catch (Exception $e){

        }
    }
```

If you want you can also adapt this to fill the field and trigger the event after.
For checking the event that you need to trigger you need to inspect that element and check that `ev` in the inspector.

Comment: So do I have to place this code before or after filling the field?

Comment: Ok I got it, I had to do some tweaks to adapt my code to your solution, and it works like a charm, thank you!